# Report.NET TableLayoutManager example needed

Tags: .net, pdf

Has anyone used the Report.NET library from http://report.sourceforge.net/ to create PDF documents?

There is no example code for the TableLayoutManager and the API is confusing the hell out of me.

Can anyone point me to some example code?

Thanks

David

Comment: Can you just give an example scenario what you are trying to implement. So we can give specific implementation.

Comment: Sure. Just give me code for a PDF with a paragraph of text, then a four by four table containing the numbers 1 to 16, then another paragraph of text.

Good luck!